# Kafka consumer to wait till all similar messages arrived

Tags: apache-kafka

We have a requirement scenario that consumer to wait till all similar messages arrived in Topic. For example all the invoices of similar "email aaaaa@gmai.com" should come before consumer start consuming all invoices with email aaaaa@gmai.com . Basically all Invoices should be grouped against same email.

Comment: How will you know when all the similar messages have arrived? Would it be better to plan to put each message in the correct place when it arrives?

Comment: Each emailAdress in message have a property how many invoice it have

Comment: And how does that help when "all similar message arrive"?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible. Kafka server nor consumer will know when something is "complete"; only your own application logic. Data within a topic is only ordered by producer sends (by offset, per partition) not "by email (or other embedded, serialized field) / event-type"

You'll need to explicitly aggregate data, such as in a KTable or remote database upon consumption, then parse out what it means for events to be "similar", or when a batch is "complete" (which may never happen if the producer doesn't send such event)

Comment: Every message have a property that how many counts this email have. If all are available need to consume else need to wait

Comment: Then send data within an array of each record, not just an integer that means nothing to Kafka